# Unable to test iOS app on iPad with Flash Builder 4.7 OSX Yosemite

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder, osx-yosemite

After upgrading to OSX Yosemite, i'm unable to test my iOS app on my device.
Compilation and packaging works as expected but app is never installed on my device connected trough USB.

Anyone having the same problem?
Thanks

Comment: Is everything updated to latest - flash, air sdk, etc. ?

Comment: I'm using Flex 4.6 and AIR 15.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution on another post having app installation problem on Mavericks.

Disable your device WiFi and install your application from Flash Builder. Then enable your device wifi. It work for me.

Thanks

Comment: Here is the post stating the wifi problem: https://forums.adobe.com/message/7087058#7087058